# Why we add attributes under class's constructor and not above it?

Tags: class, oop, dart, constructor

I have noticed that many skilled developers insist to add attributes under the class's constructor and not above it, why it is important? is it for best practices or something else ?

```
Class Car{
String color;
int speed;
Car({this.color, this.speed});
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
Class Car{
Car({this.color, this.speed});
String color;
int speed;
}
```

Thanks?

Comment: Removed the java tag because the code certainly is not java. (and in java there is no difference between the declaration locations)

Comment: thanks @luk2302 for the correction but still didn't answer my question

Comment: Wasn't trying to because I know nothing about dart. I suspect this should be closed as primarily opinion-based because the choice is just a personal preference but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Yes, thanks i can see, but i gave an example with Dart because i can't write it in all different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no semantic difference, it's all about what the author thinks is more important.

The [Dart style guide](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) is silent on the issue, so it's purely tradition, and tradition differs between projects and between people coming from other languages.

I personally put instance variables before constructors because *when editing the code*, knowing the state of the object is more important to me than what the constructors are.
I've seen others put instance variables at the very end of the class with the same reasoning.
What is important is that you can quickly find what you are looking for when working with the code. Being consistent is more important than anything else.

Others put constructors first because that's the first thing a user of the class will need to know about it. I personally think that's irrelevant, and the user should use the API docs, not the source code, when studying the class (which only works for public classes, obviously).